# Should MSVC reject an templated using without instantiation

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, clang, language-lawyer

The following code compiles with Clang (4.0) and GCC (6.3), but fails with MSVC (Visual Studio 2015 Update 1, Visual Studio 2017).

```
template <typename T>
using ConstRestrict = T const __restrict;
```

MSVC emits the error:

> error C2219: syntax error: type qualifier must be after '*'

However, the following code compiles fine with MSVC:

```
using ConstRestrictInt = ConstRestrict<int*>;
```

Is this a compiler bug? What does the standard say about this?

Comment: Please provide [mcve], not snippets with typos.  What **exactly** compiles and does not?  Both statements together?  Apart?  Did you drop the `;` on purpose?

Comment: No. This the minimal complete and verifiable example... https://godbolt.org/g/pqrJFr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__restrict` is not a valid keyword in C++ (any version), and its use is reserved for the implementation so there is nothing you can `#define` it to to make your code valid.

MSVC rejecting your code is standard compliant.  The standard makes no requirements that non-standard code be accepted.

I answer this way because it of the [language-lawyer](/questions/tagged/language-lawyer) and your request for what the standard says.

Practically it is probably a bug with its implementation of its `__restrict` extension.  It should either reject such an alias or accept it.